# How to expand groupby df Pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have filtered a pandas data frame by grouping and taking sum, now I want all the details and no longer need the sum

for example what I have looks like the image below

[image: what i have]

what i want is for each of the individual transactions to be shown, as currently the amount column is the sum of all transactions done by an individual on a specific date i want to see all the individual amounts, is this possible?

I dont know how to filter the larger df by the groupby one, have also tried using isin() with multiple &s but it does not work as for example "David" could be in my groupby df on sept 15, but in the larger df he has made transactions on other days aswell and those are slipping through when using isin()

Comment: please give an example code for your dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello there and welcome,

first of all, as I've learned my self, always try:

- to give some data (in text, or code form) as your input
- share your expected output, to avoid more questions
- have fun :-)

I'm new as well, and I did my best to cover as much possibilities as I could, at least people can use my code to get your df.

```
#From the picture
data={'Date': ['2014-06-30','2014-07-02','2014-07-02','2014-07-03','2014-07-09','2014-07-14','2014-07-17','2014-07-25','2014-07-29','2014-07-29','2014-08-06','2014-08-11','2014-08-22'],
      'LastName':['Cow','Kind','Lion','Steel','Torn','White','Goth','Hin','Hin','Torn','Goth','Hin','Hin'],
      'FirstName':['C','J','K','J','M','D','M','G','G','M','M','G','G'],
      'Vendor':['Jail','Vet','TGI','Dept','Show','Still','Turf','Glass','Sup','Ref','Turf','Lock','Brenn'],
      'Amount': [5015.70,6293.27,7043.00,7600,9887.08,5131.74,5037.55,5273.55,9455.48,5003.71,6675,7670.5,8698.18]
      }

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

incoming=df.groupby(['Date','LastName','FirstName','Vendor','Amount']).count()
#what I believe you did to get Date grouped
incoming
```

Now here my answer:

Firstly I merged First and Lastname

```
df['CompleteName']=df[['FirstName','LastName']].agg('.'.join,axis=1) # getting Names for df
```

Then I did some statistics for the amount, for different groups:

```
#creating a new column with as much Statistics from group (Complete Name, Date, Vendor, etc.)
df['AmountSumName']=df['Amount'].groupby(df['CompleteName']).transform('sum')
df['AmountSumDate']=df['Amount'].groupby(df['Date']).transform('sum')
df['AmountSumVendor']=df['Amount'].groupby(df['Vendor']).transform('sum')
df
```

Now just groupby as you wish

Hope I could answer you question.

Comment: Thank you very much, you did indeed answer my question, I will for sure keep in mind to submit my code as well. New to this.

Comment: @Relaxeddevil thx you for your feedback, please kindly mark the question as answered, in order to recognise the author of the answer and to close the question as well.